# In g+++ unable to print large string

Tags: c++

The sendbyts prints all values when the string is smaller than 15 bytes . I verified the content with strtok and all details are present in the string. I am not able to output the whole string with cout<

```
 for(i=0;i<=1;i++){
             sendbyts= peerinfo[i].n_ip;
             sendbyts.append(" ");
             cout<< peerinfo[i].n_ip<<"\n";  
            //verify whether the right data is appended                  
             sendbyts.append(peerinfo[i].n_portno);
             sendbyts.append(" ");
             cout<< peerinfo[i].n_portno<<"\n";
             cout<<"verify the string here :"<<sendbyts<<"\n";
             sendbyts.append("0x0");
             sendbyts.append(" ");
             cout<<" \n verify the string again :"<<sendbyts<<"\n";
             sendbyts.append(peerinfo[i].n_sno);
             sendbyts.append(" ");
             cout<<peerinfo[i].n_sno<<"\n";
             sendbyts.append("|");
             cout<<" \n final verification  :"<<sendbyts<<"\n";
     }
     cout<<"final string formed  "<<sendbyts<<"\n";

     output
     128.205.36.8
     6666
     erify the string here :128.205.36.8 6666
     0x0 fy the string again :128.205.36.8 6666
     0x0 1 |erification  128.205.36.8 6666

     Expected output
     128.205.36.8
     6666
     verify the string here :128.205.36.8 6666128.205.36.8 6666
     verify the string again :128.205.36.8 6666 0x0
     final verification :128.205.36.8 6666 0x0 1|
```

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: can you use a debugger do dump the content of sendbyts?

Comment: 0x0 5 -1|ng formed  128.205.36.25 5555
this actually should have been " the final string formed 128.205.36.25 5555 0x0 0 1 2 |

Comment: The stream is not able to print out the whole cout<< . The contents are getting garbled and the whole string is not getting printed

Comment: Please add input data, observed behavior, and expected behaviour to the question, with an eye on proper formatting. Otherwise, making sense of your (rather poor) code will be difficult. You might also try to reduce the amount of code necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: There is no type information here, that makes it more difficult. In fact, a complete test example would be good. Did you try deleting code until the problem resolved?

Comment: every thing within the structure peerinfo is a string . hope the code is clearer now

Comment: The members of `peerinfo` are `string` or `char*`?

Comment: Also your for loop termination condition is unusual. Usually it would be less-than, not less-than-or-equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You output looks like it's printing a carriage return ('\r') without a newline. When this happens, the cursor goes back to the start of the line without moving down. The subsequent text is printed over the last text.

Try changing any '\r' characters to '\n' characters.

Comment: Thanks found the problem there is tab included in the end of portno string which is causing this issue. I am not sure if it is a tab though . When i did a substr to end of line from a getline the character got appended .